# two strings identical, but not equal when compared

Tags: php, string-comparison

I have this little problem i couldn't solve on my own, i'm comparing two strings that are identical one taken from the database and the other from a text file, the values are always equal except for the last one

**CODE FOR ARRAY FROM TEXT FILE**

```
while (!feof($monfichier)) {
    $line = fgets($monfichier);
    $pieces = explode(" ", $line);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][0] = $pieces[0]; //id client
    $factureAgent[$nbb][1] = $pieces[1]; //consommation annuelle
    $factureAgent[$nbb][2] = $pieces[2]; //année
    $factureAgent[$nbb][3] = $pieces[3]; //id agent
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[4]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][4] = $month[1]; //janvier
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[5]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][5] = $month[1]; //fevrier
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[6]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][6] = $month[1]; //mars
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[7]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][7] = $month[1]; //avril
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[8]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][8] = $month[1]; //mai
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[9]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][9] = $month[1]; //juin
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[10]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][10] = $month[1]; //juillet
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[11]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][11] = $month[1]; //aout
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[12]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][12] = $month[1]; //septembre
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[13]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][13] = $month[1]; //octobre
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[14]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][14] = $month[1]; //novembre
    $month = explode(":", $pieces[15]);
    $factureAgent[$nbb][15] = $month[1]; //decembre
    $nbb++;
}
```

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
echo "<br>".$row[0]."is".$factureAgent[$i][$nb]."<br>";
if ($année==$annéeComp[0]) {
  if ($row[0]!=$factureAgent[$i][$nb]) {
    echo "<br>".$row[0]."is".$factureAgent[$i][$nb]."<br>";
    $ok = false;
  }
  $nb++;
  $nbr++;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

> 25is25
>   50is50
>   87is87
>   115is115
>   200is200
>   250is250
>   400is400
>   550is500
>   600is600
>   650is650
>   800is800
>   950is950
>   950is950

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh2Ub.png)

**LINE I'M READING FROM TEXT FILE**

> 1 2000 2019 1 01:25 02:50 03:87 04:115 05:200 06:250 07:400 08:550 09:600 10:650 11:800 12:950
>   13 2000 2019 1 01:45 02:90 03:150 04:300 05:600 06:800 07:1000 08:1300 09:1450 10:1600 11:1800 12:2000

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QveJh.png)

Comment: Try providing a bit more code. Also please provide _text_ output and input files as .. you know.. text, not images.

Comment: @redreinard ok, i didn't want to put too much code in there, but i'll try to add some more.

Comment: @redreinard i added some more code i don't if it's going helpful, but let me know.

Comment: How do you know they are not equal? The output you're seeing might be from the first line of PHP.

Comment: @showdev i have an output that's always showing, and the other only shows inside if, and i also increment $nb, so the array reaches it's end in the end, the problem was solved by converting the string to an int, but still i wanna know the reason why things went wrong with strings .

Comment: Oh I see, output of the last row is doubled. To troubleshoot the string comparison, you might get some info by outputting the variable types: `var_dump($row[0]); var_dump($factureAgent[$i][$nb]);`.

Comment: is it possible there is an empty row in your input file at the end, or an extra space at the end? Try adding something like `if (!strlen(trim($line))) continue;` after reading the line from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing string from different sources can lead to unexpected results.

One thing you can do is casting your values to the same type and then compare. 
For example:

`if (intval('1') === intval('01')) ...`

This way you are getting the two sides to integer and its just an integer comparison.

Note that if you cast a value which is not numeric the function will always return 0

Answer (score 0):

That is maybe you are using `==` instead of `===`.
i might suggest using `strcasecmp` if you do not want the case to be considered or use `strcmp` if you want case to be considered.

[strcasecmp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)

[strcmp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php)

pay attention to the comparison of the result of these to functions to 0 with `===` so that you be sure they are equal for example:
`if (strcmp('Hello, 'Hello') === 0) ...`

Be aware when using `==` and `===`

`(1 == '1') //Equal -- not taking into consideration the type but just the value`

`(1 === '1') //Not equal -- taking into consideration the type and the value`

Just for your information for not you use `!=` or `!==`

Comment: i did try that, but it didn't workout, i'm just comparing numbers, so it's not case sensitive

Comment: try maybe casting the values to int using intval($value) and then compare

Comment: yes, that did workout, although i still don't know why it doesn't workout with strings but thanks. you should answer with that comment.